# Metadata in Document library missing when copied from one document library to another document library using Explorer view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I have two document libraries with same associated content type in two different sub sites in a site collection. I have uploaded a document by setting the column values. Now, if I copy a file from on library using open with explorer and paste in another library using the explorer then document is copied but the column/properties values are not copied.

If I create a document using the content type "New Document" instead of using the "Upload" button then the same process copied the document along with its properties/column values.

Is this the expected behavior that metadata/column values copied from one library to another only if we create the document using content type but not if we directly use upload option?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior as it can carry only few metadata with file while open in File Explorer like "Name", "Date Modified" , "Size" ,"Modified By" other Custom column which is not supported by Files will not be carry over to the destination Library.

here is [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-open-with-explorer-aaee7bfb-e2a1-42ee-8fc0-bcc0754f04d2?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) reference

if you want to move the document from One Library to another Library with Metadata intact you should use below steps:

1. Go to http://SharepointSiteURL/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx
2. Click on the library from which you would like to move the doucments and this should provide you the list of the all documents
3. Select all/documents you would like to move
4. From the menu, under "Actions" there is option to Move/Copy.
5. Select the destination doucment Lib

you can follow this [link](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/move-files-between-document-libraries-with-metadata-version-history.html) for more detail answer

Comment: Is there a way for user to be promped to add metadata when they are just using the explorer to upload something to the Document Library ?

Comment: @Ed1995 , sorry i am not aware of if any possibilities is there to prompt user to add metadata